# Help splitting a custom post type archive into "past" and "upcoming"

Tags: custom-post-types, template-hierarchy

I'm working on a wordpress site that keeps track of a series of `event` posts (custom post type), and I'd like to split up my `archive-event.php` page into two sections – "upcoming events" and "past events," based on today's date.

Using `meta_query`, I've been able to successfully show only events which have not yet happened, based on today's date. Changing my query to show past events instead of future ones should not be difficult.

What I don't understand is how to enable both of these queries at the same time. Is there a way to create a second `archive-post-type.php` page for my custom post type? Alternatively, is there a way to create a new page template (ex. `past-events.php`) and somehow connect add it into the site's template hierarchy?

By way of context, the page I'm trying to modify is here: http://artsrestore.la/events/

And you can see the `archive-event.php` code here: https://gist.github.com/egardner/7324310

Many thanks,
Eric

Also – I'm pretty new at wordpress and PHP generally, so explanations of code are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You almost did everything there is to do. After your _Upcoming Events_ query just add another `WP_Query` with according arguments. And don't forget to call `wp_reset_postdata` after you're finished, in order you want to work with the _original_ query in some way...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! It sounds like if I did this both upcoming & past events would be displayed at once. I'd like the default to upcoming with an option to show past instead (but not both at the same time). Would this require the creation of a separate template file (and if so, where would it go)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing we can do to make this more efficient, is to get rid of the query in your post type archive template. That page is already loading your events in the main query, and you're then running a new query in the template, so this is a waste of a query.

What we'll do instead is use the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action to add the meta query *before* the main query is run. We can then use the normal `while( have_posts() )` loop in the template, and not the custom query loop. There's an extra bit in here to handle past events that won't make sense until the next step, so keep reading:

```
function event_post_order( $query ){
    // if this is not an admin screen,
    // and is the event post type archive
    // and is the main query
    if( ! is_admin()
        && $query->is_post_type_archive( 'event' )
        && $query->is_main_query() ){

        // if this is a past events view
        // set compare to before today,
        // otherwise set to today or later
        $compare = isset( $query->query_vars['is_past'] ) ? '<' : '>=';

        // add the meta query and use the $compare var
        $today = date( 'Y-m-d' );
        $meta_query = array( array( 
            'key' => 'sort_date',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => $compare,
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ) );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'event_post_order' );
```

Now to get the past events working, we'll add a couple of rewrite rules to handle `events/past`, plus pagination. Your `archive-event.php` template will be used for both upcoming and past, so no need for new templates.

This is also where we add the `is_past` rewrite tag, so we can check in the previous step if it's a past events view:

```
function event_archive_rewrites(){
    add_rewrite_tag( '%is_past%','([^&]+)' );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'events/past/page/([0-9]+)/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=event&paged=$matches[1]&is_past=true',
        'top'
    );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'events/past/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=event&is_past=true',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'event_archive_rewrites' );
```

So that's it. Visit your `Settings > Permalinks` admin page after adding this code to your theme's `functions.php` file to flush rewrite rules, or you could [put it in a plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the very thorough response! I assume I would then just manually add a link to `events/past`  (or something along those lines) in the `archive-event.php` template to change between queries?

Comment: yes, correct. and you're welcome!

Comment: Okay, I added those functions as well as `<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/events/past">Past Events</a>` to the `archive-event.php` page (and removed the original query there) – but the query doesn't seem to be switching over. I flushed the rewrite rules as well. Is this the correct usage here?

Comment: add `var_dump( $wp_query );` to your template and inspect the query vars to make sure they're getting set correctly. I'd also suggest disabling your cache plugin to be sure there isn't a conflict. and add a training slash to your past events link, you're getting an extra http request / redirect each time WordPress forwards to the version with the trailing slash.

Comment: Thanks again – I got everything working now! I just noticed I was still calling `if ($the_query -> have_posts() )` instead of just `if ( have_posts() )`. Once I reverted to the default query everything fell into place.

Comment: After this, as only one archive template is being used, what conditional function can be used to check for `is_past()` or similar? So if we're viewing the 'upcoming events' part, we can display a link to show the past events?

Comment: @Lee `get_query_var('is_past')` will return `true` if it was set in the current request.